# Pop!_OS: can't open gnome-panel from terminal

Tags: linux, gnome

When I enter `gnome-panel` in my terminal, I get this warning and gnome panel doesn't open. It doesn't look like it's running when I use htop. I tried rebooting but got the same warning. I can do some things with gnome-panel from the command line like add desktop shortcuts, but I want to access the gui.

```
** (gnome-panel:5530): WARNING **: 14:55:55.477: Failed to request name: the name already has an owner
```

system specs:

```
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="18.04 LTS"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Pop!_OS 18.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
```

Comment: Don;t forget to check for an answer at http://pop.system76.com/docs , http://reddit.com/r/pop_os , and chat.pop-os.org,